# NameError: name 'IMG_H' is not defined

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, python-imaging-library, histogram

I am a new programming Interface. I am using the PIL and Matplotlib libraries for the contract streaching.When I am using the Histogram Equalizer I am getting the error as name 'IMG_H' is not defined.I am also Converting my  image to numpy array, calculate the histogram, cumulative sum, mapping and then apply the mapping to create a new image.
You can see my code below -

```
# HISTOGRAM EQUALIZATION
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
def make_histogram(img):
 """ Take an image and create a historgram from it's luma values """
 y_vals = img[:,:,0].flatten()
 histogram = np.zeros(256, dtype=int)
 for y_index in range(y_vals.size):
     histogram[y_vals[y_index]] += 1
 return histogram

def make_cumsum(histogram):
 """ Create an array that represents the cumulative sum of the histogram """
 cumsum = np.zeros(256, dtype=int)
 cumsum[0] = histogram[0]
 for i in range(1, histogram.size):
     cumsum[i] = cumsum[i-1] + histogram[i]
 return cumsum

def make_mapping(histogram, cumsum):
 
 mapping = np.zeros(256, dtype=int)
 luma_levels = 256
 for i in range(histogram.size):
     mapping[i] = max(0, round((luma_levels*cumsum[i])/(IMG_H*IMG_W))-1)
 return mapping

def apply_mapping(img, mapping):
 """ Apply the mapping to our image """
 new_image = img.copy()
 new_image[:,:,0] = list(map(lambda a : mapping[a], img[:,:,0]))
 return new_image


# Load image
pillow_img = Image.open('pout.jpg')
# Convert our image to numpy array, calculate the histogram, cumulative sum,
# mapping and then apply the mapping to create a new image
img = np.array(pillow_img)
histogram = make_histogram(img)
cumsum = make_cumsum(histogram)
mapping = make_mapping(histogram, cumsum)
new_image = apply_mapping(img, mapping)
output_image = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(new_image))
imshow(output_image, cmap='gray')

# Display the old (black) and new (red) histograms next to eachother
x_axis = np.arange(256)
fig = plt.figure()
fig.add_subplot(1,2,1)
plt.bar(x_axis , histogram, color = "black")
fig.add_subplot(1,2,2)
plt.bar(x_axis , make_histogram(new_image), color = "red")
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have this variable here:

```
mapping[i] = max(0, round((luma_levels*cumsum[i])/(IMG_H*IMG_W))-1)
```

But you didn't define it (or import) before, therefore you get this error.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(histogram.size):
 mapping[i] = max(0, round((luma_levels*cumsum[i])/(IMG_H*IMG_W))-1)
```

In above stated line. you are using 2 Variables, IMG_H and IMG_W.

where you defined these variables?

> EDITED PART

```
for i in range(histogram.size):
 mapping[i] = max(0, round((luma_levels*cumsum[i])/(IMG_H*IMG_W))-1)
```

in the above stated line you are using 2 variables try to do multiplication (IMG_H*IMG_W) but you did not define and import these variables in the whole code.

You can do like this.

you can define these variables on the top of the code.

your code shows that these variables are defined for Image width and height

```
IMG_W = 120   #Any value in integer for Image Width
IMG_H = 124   #Any value in integer for Image Height
```

Comment: How to define(import)  these variables could you help me.

Comment: I think you are using these variables to set Image Height and Image Width, Have you set width and height anywhere in this code? or in any other file?

Comment: Are you familiar with variables in Python?? I am editing my code you can see there how variables work